# rails app showing files instead of showing the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, .htaccess, deployment

i using the bluehost shared sever

it should be a shown in the root domain domainname.com

the rails files are under:

```
public_html/app_name/current
```

my public_html/.htaccess has:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app_name/current/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_name/current/public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /app_name/current/public/ [L]
```

my public_html/app_name/current/public/.htaccess has:

```
Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
RailsEnv production
RackBaseURI /public_html/app_name/current       
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home1/username/ruby/gems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I solve myself, i'll post the answer, this may help somebody
things started to become clear when I added to my public_html/app_name/current/public/.htaccess

```
PassengerAppRoot /home1/user/public_html/app_name/current
```

then I started to see a blank page and started to show in the rails logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/app_name/current/public"):
```

then I realized, ok Rails is running, now it's a routing problem, but why it is showing "/app_name/current/public" in the logs since im not trying to access this route?
well and it is the same path in my public_html/.htaccess, then I've figured out that I had all the system variables to reference my rails paths in my public_html/app_name/current/public/.htaccess I have to get rid of public_html/.htaccess configurations.

so, I've deleted the public_html/app_name/current/public/.htaccess file and added everythin to the public_html/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$  

Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
RailsEnv production
RackBaseURI /public_html/app_name/current
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home1/user/ruby/gems
PassengerAppRoot /home1/user/public_html/app_name/current
```

then I ran into a problem where my images under public/uploads weren't displaying so i've added:

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$  /faux/current/public/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Nice one - love it when people share their solutions :) So you're using Apache with Passenger?

Comment: Hello Rich, Yes, Apache with Passenger :)